# Не могу указать фиксированную высоту элементу на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Требуется задать фиксированную высоту для блока `features-slider-front` в слайдере.

```css
/*Стилизация блоков слайдера*/

.features-block {
  font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
  background: rgba(248, 243, 243, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  outline: none;
}

.features-block>h4 {
  margin-top: 13px;
  color: rgb(43, 75, 103);
  font-size: 18px;
}

.features-block>p {
  color: #042A4B;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.features-block>button {
  color: #fff;
  background: #042A4B;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 3px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.features-block>button:hover {
  background: #8FB7F0;
}


/*Стилизация блоков слайдера с фронтальной стороны*/

.features-block-front>h3 {
  margin-top: 13px;
  color: rgb(43, 75, 103);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.features-slider-front {
  height: 386px;
}
```

```html
<section class="features">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2 class="section-header">
          Преимущества работы с нами:
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="features-slider">
      <div class="features-block">
        <h4>Бизнес сайт</h4>
        <img class="image" src="img/beeznes-sait.png" alt="">
        <p>6900 руб.</p>
        <button>Подробнее</button>
      </div>
      <div class="features-block features-block-front">
        <h3>Бизнес сайт</h3>
        <span class="front">Выгодное предложение для желающих рассказать о своих товарах и услугах.
              В стоимость бизнес сайта включены такие модули как:
              - Фотогаллерея
              - Каталог товаров
             </span>
        <button>Подробнее</button>
      </div>
      <div class="features-block">
        <h4>Премиум</h4>
        <img class="image" src="img/premium.png" alt="">
        <p>12800 руб.</p>
        <button>Подробнее</button>
      </div>
      <div class="features-block">
        <h4>Базовый Лендинг</h4>
        <img class="image" src="img/bazovy_ledding.png" alt="">
        <p>6900 руб.</p>
        <button>Подробнее</button>
      </div>
      <div class="features-block">
        <h4>Интернет магазин</h4>
        <img class="image" src="img/internet_shop.png" alt="">
        <p>7900 руб.</p>
        <button>Подробнее</button>
      </div>
      <div class="features-block">
        <h4>Экстра сайт</h4>
        <img class="image" src="img/exstra-sait.png" alt="">
        <p>15600 руб.</p>
        <button>Подробнее</button>
      </div>
      <div class="features-block">
        <h4>Как себе</h4>
        <img class="image" src="img/kak-sebe.png" alt="">
        <p>35000</p>
        <button>Подробнее</button>
      </div>
      <div class="features-block">
        <h4>Cosmo</h4>
        <img class="image" src="img/cosmo.png" alt="">
        <p>50000</p>
        <button>Подробнее</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Я вам советую использовать `display: flex;`, поддержка у браузеров уже хорошая, `align-items: stretch;` но нужно настроить wrap'ы будет.

Comment: высота все равно не работает Мне нужно чтобы она была строго 368px но блок это свойство просто игнорирует

Comment: Если вы выставляете для класса `.features-block` свойство `height: 368px;` у вас блоки не становятся этой высоты?

Comment: Только сейчас увидел что вы хотите высоту выставить для блока с классом `features-slider-front` но у вас в html нет такого блока.

Comment: все равно он не хочет фиксированную высоту ставить. А мне нужно чтобы он был как другие элементы чтобы потом сделать через css 3-d карточку с вращением

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
min-height: 386px;
```